# Rendering happens without waiting for API data in React JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am new in ReactJS and I am creating single registration page App where drop-down data is from API, but when I am trying to fetch the data there is error showing.

my Sample code is below:

**AppApi.js:**

```
var AppActions =require('../actions/AppActions');
var request = require('superagent');

var Data= {};
module.exports ={
        request.get('*http://api.randomuser.me/*')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .end(function(err, response) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
           Data.details= response.text;
        AppActions.receiveData(Data.details);


      });
}
```

**my Action is:**

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
var AppConstants = require('../constants/AppConstants');
var AppActions = {
    receiveData: function(data){
      AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
          actionType: AppConstants.RECEIVE_DATA,
          data: data
      })
  }
 }
module.exports= AppActions;
```

**my ConstantFile is:**

```
module.exports ={
    RECEIVE_GENDERS: 'RECEIVE_GENDERS'
}
```

Dispatcher is:

```
    var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher;
    var assign = require('object-assign');
    var AppDispatcher= assign( new Dispatcher(), {
        handleViewAction :function(action){
            var payload ={
                source: 'VIEW_ACTION',
                action: action
            }
            this.dispatch(payload);
        }
    });
   module.exports =AppDispatcher;
```

**in my Store:**

```
 var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
    var AppConstants = require('../constants/AppConstants');
    var EventEmitter =require('events').EventEmitter;
    var assign =require('object-assign');
    var AppAPI = require('../utils/appAPI.js');

    var CHANGE_EVENT ='change';
    var _data=[];
    var AppStore= assign({ }, EventEmitter.prototype, {
        setData: function(data){
            console.log("my Data", data);
            _data=data
    }, 
         getData: function(){
            //not getting data in console
            console.log("returning Data", _data);
            return _data;
        },
         emitChange: function(){
            this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
        },
        addChangeListener : function(callback){
            this.on('change', callback);
        },
        removeChangeListener: function(callback){
            this.removeListener('change',callback)
        }
    });
    AppDispatcher.register(function(payload){
        var action = payload.action;
        switch(action.actionType){
              case AppConstants.RECEIVE_DATA:
                AppStore.setData(action.data);
                AppStore.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
                break;
    }
        return true;
    });

    module.exports =AppStore;
```

**my Main.js is:**

```
var App= require('./components/App');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDom = require('react-dom');
var AppAPI = require('./utils/appAPI.js');

AppAPI.getGenders();
ReactDom.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**and My APP.JS is in following format:**

```
var React =require('react');
var AppActions = require('../actions/AppActions');
var AppStore = require('../stores/AppStore');
function getAppState(){
    return{
        data: AppStore.getData()
    }
}

var App= React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        console.log(getAppState().data)
        return getAppState()
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){
        AppStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    }, 
    componentWillUnmount: function(){
        AppStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },
    render: function(){
},
        _onChange: function(){
            this.setState(getAppState());
        }
});
module.exports =App;
```

**Problem:**  empty object getting in console.log(getAppState().data) because rendering part is not waiting for ajax data.

please help me or give me some solution for this problem, I am struggling with it since last 3 days.
**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to avoid rendering a react component because data are not loaded yet, you can condition the component displaying this way:

```
return{
  <div>
  {
    this.state.data?
      <ComponentExample data={this.state.data}/>
    :
      null
  }
  </div>
}
```

There is other ways to condition component rendering, like using a [stateless component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions), but this ways will work just fine.

Otherwise, It is not a problem that you got an empty object in `getInitialState()`: It is right that you lack data at first rendering, but as soon as data from your API will be retreived, thanks to `_onChange()`,the component will be re-rendered and as a result, `ComponentExample` could be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAppState(){
    return{
        data: AppStore.getData(),
        status:AppStore.getStatus()
    }
}
```

add getStatus function to AppStore

```
render: function(){
   if(this.state.status=='loading')
       return (<div className="loading"></div>);
   if ....
   return (<RealComponent data={this.state.data}></RealComponent>)
},
```